# Subsets with different metrics

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Can a set have two proper subsets that have different metrics? Similarly, can a metric space have subsets with a different metric than itself or even no metric?

I the answer is yes to one or both questions, I would also appreciate some explanation of how this is coherent.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I can always construct a metric for any given set (discrete metric). If you wish, you can define infinitely many different metrics on any given nonempty set.

Comment: A subspace of a metric space has an induced metric, but you are always free to chose another metric for any space. There is no notion of "the" metric of a space, and some spaces are not even metrizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets do not come equipped with metrics; rather, a metric is something you can give to a set.

An analogy: wood does not come equipped with paint; rather, paint is something you can apply to wood. Of course, there are many different colors of paint that you could choose to apply to any piece of wood, or indeed you could choose to not paint your wood at all. In exactly the same way, there may be many different metrics you could choose to equip a set with, or you could choose not to give a set a metric at all.

Painting a piece of wood really gives you a new object: you no longer have just a piece of wood, you have a piece of wood *with paint on it*. Likewise, equipping a set with a metric gives you a new object: you no longer have just a set, you have a set *with a metric on it* (aka a metric space).

The same piece of wood (the same set), given two different colors of paint (two different metrics), will yield two different painted pieces of wood (two different metric spaces).

If you have a large painted piece of wood (a metric space) and you cut off a small piece of it (a subset), you now have a smaller painted piece of wood (your subspace with the induced metric). But of course you could repaint this smaller piece (give it a new metric) if you'd like!

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful!